# Apply css to elements of div in parents inline style

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code ,

```
<div class="parent">

</div>
```

I am adding one div inside the parent div on runtime, It would be like this ,

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class='child'>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there is any way to add style to child div using parent div ? Means can I do something like ,

```
<div class="parent" style="SET LEFT MARGIN FOR CHILD ELEMENT ">

</div>
```

So when child is added to parent div , the style will be automatically applied to child.

Comment: Couldn't you set a css rule like this?

.parent .child {
 margin-left: XXXXpx;
}

Comment: Why not set the child div's properties in your stylesheet?...

Comment: As I mentioned in question, I want to make in style attribute of div.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes I know this , But I want to know whether it is possible to add in style attribute of div ?

Comment: No. The inline style attribute only styles the element on which it is applied. However, some CSS properties may be inherited by children.

Comment: @torazaburo Thank you very much. Can I delete the question now ?

Comment: @Fledgling Up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Based on specification — no, you can't.
http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly with inline css on parent div. But you can inherit styles from parent div like this:

**CSS:**

```
.child {
  margin-left: inherit;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent" style="margin-left: 15px;">
  <div class="child"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close to a general solution, only issue would occur if you wanted to style the parent and the child differently using the same attribute. However with that being said this works perfectly for me as I using this approach intentionally to have the child match the parent!

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the **.child** tags with i.e. < span > or < div > in this case, then set the inline CSS for the **.parent** tags, and then use **"inherit"** on the **.child** tag.

```
<div class="parent" style="color:yellow;">
   <div class="child" style="color:inherit;">
   </div>
</div>
```

The same was a successful solution applied to a similar problem I was facing regarding **how the emails or links appeared inside a Gmail message body**.

```
<div>
   Hello <span style="color:yellow;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:inherit !important;">SomeMail@gmail.com</a></span>, we have just posted this on our website:
   <br/>
   <a href="#" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="#">Page Title of Website</a>
</div>
```

I hope this offers a solution to your situation or at least inspires you closer to your preferred remedy.

Answer (score -2):

Using the `>` for direct children:

```
.parent > div {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: @ashleedawg Well, my answer was first, so I'm not sure what you're accusing me of.    While I could have mentioned that it's not possible explicitly, something like this is the only alternative. It's odd you don't seem concerned with the answer suggesting a separate class, though.

Comment: @scorpion No, this answer is not spam. Please see the help center to learn what spam is.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class='child'>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .parent >.child {
    margin-left: 30px;
    }
```

Comment: This is not an inline style as requested.